# Docker Compose Rails Tutorial: Where did the files go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have been following the [Docker Compose Rails tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/). It has been doing fine until when I run `docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle` (ok well, installation went fine :) )

Here's what happens:

```
▶ sudo docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
Creating dockers_db_1...
Building web...
Step 0 : FROM ruby:2.1.4
 ---> 766162a99b23
Step 1 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0053b73703c1
Step 2 : RUN mkdir /myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf768c1e06ca
Step 3 : WORKDIR /myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 934af3ef8124
Step 4 : ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3666057e0d52
Step 5 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e796e93e83d6
Step 6 : ADD . /myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03249ac42a63
Successfully built 03249ac42a63
       exist  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
       force  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
```

So I'm like "oh cool, it works".

But then I need to edit the `Gemfile`. The host `Gemfile` hasn't changed:

```
cat Gemfile 
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
```

So I reckon I need to go into my docker:

```
▶ sudo docker images                         
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
workspace_web       latest              03249ac42a63        8 hours ago         835.3 MB
dockers_web         latest              03249ac42a63        8 hours ago         835.3 MB
postgres            latest              7bf0ec35adaf        6 days ago          214 MB
hello-world         latest              91c95931e552        9 weeks ago         910 B
ruby                2.1.4               766162a99b23        7 months ago        798.3 MB
```

But there the file looks the same:

```
▶ sudo docker run -t -i workspace_web /bin/bash
root@400ca3fd62a7:/myapp# cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
```

Where did the `rails new` generated files go? Been searching around, without success.

I'm on Debian, so not using Boot2docker.

Thanks

Comment: Did you go into the myapp directory?

Comment: Yes. I actually start into `/myapp` (in my case `myapp` is called `copass` but I edited it now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `docker-compose.yml` notice the following lines:

```
volumes:
- .:/myapp
```

`/myapp` was mapped to the current dir you were in when you ran `docker-compose run` - so that's where you should look for the files.

when you `sudo docker run -t -i workspace_web /bin/bash` you didn't add `-v .:/mapp` so your `/myapp` folder with the files wasn't mounted and remains empty volume within the container.

Comment: you can also use `docker inspect -f "{{.Volumes}}" <directory>_web_1` to figure out where that was. This will inspect the container (if it's still around), compose uses the name of the directory, the service and a counter (for scaling) to name the containers it creates.

Answer (score 1):

[docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails) is a project I just created to make rails with docker (and CI) *very easy*.  I think it can help you and reduce the amount of configuration necessary to get up and running with rails on docker.

It will also help you *extract* any of these files back to the host.  In my performance testing, doing something like:

```
volumes:
- .:/myapp
```

is up to **4x slower** because it is mounting a volume `.` on the host.  Instead, as done in the sample for [docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails), use a `Dockerfile` `VOLUME` for almost native I/O speed (bypassed any union file system) and `COPY` for your project directory.  This means all your files will reside in the container, so you'll need to `extract` any wanted  files.  `docker-rails` makes this really easy, so for example, I use this extraction for my test artifacts:

```
  web:
    extract:
      - '/project/target'
      - '/project/vcr'
      - '/project/tmp'
      - '/project/log'
```

**TLDR;** there are a lot of tricks to getting docker/compose running right for rails.  Checkout [docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails), it has all of them in one place.

Comment: I'll have look. Thanks